# Selecting multiple columns in a pandas dataframe with separate but sequential columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
 A B C D E F
 1 3 4 2 1 4
 3 2 2 1 4 2
```

how could I select the 1st and 4th:6th columns by tags, just like:

```
df.loc[:,['A','D':'F']]
```

Comment: as marked in dupe, one can use `df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,3:5]]`

Comment: just wondering could np.r_ used with tag? or just index

Comment: `df.iloc[:,np.r_[df.columns.get_loc('A'),df.columns.get_loc('D') : df.columns.get_loc('F')]]`